# Is there a way to escape all the special characters in a url string parameter?

Tags: url, get, escaping

I need users to be able to pass a file path as a parameter of a get url (the file would not be uploaded and only the local file path is used for some security reasons). Now it's difficult for them to go and change all the backslashes to "%5". I was wondering if there is a way to force encoding of a part of the url. For example something as simple as putting it in double quotes, which doesn't work...

`http://example.com/"c:\user\somone\somefile.txt"/dosomething`

Comment: Do your users edit the URL directly, or do they enter the file path in a form?

Comment: They enter it directly, there is no UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pattern matching of rest routes at the server level. Something like this:

`/example.com/*path/dosomething`

So it would match any path even with slashes/backslashes. At last I do a decoding of the url to get rid of the escaped characters passed by browser for chars like space.

`java.net.URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8")`